# Application not starting on Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Hey guys, I inherited a project that is using Phusion Passenger and I'm not very familiar with it. I pushed my code to the server that it is hosted on and the application won't start.
Here's the trace:

```
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb  336 in `abort'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb  336 in `check_gem_dependencies'
2   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb  170 in `process'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb  113 in `send'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb  113 in `run'
5   ./config/environment.rb 15  
6   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31  in `gem_original_require'
7   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31  in `require'
```

I think that it has something to do with a gem that I added to the project, I'm just not really sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

start off by making sure all the gem dependencies are installed:

`rake gems:install`

Comment: How do I make that run on the server? I'm using capistrano to push the program to a server btw.

Comment: cap invoke COMMAND="rake gems:install"